How can I add a nested diagnostic context with Python logging package, similar log4j
I use FastAPI to develop a Python based app which is used from other services by calls to the Python endpoints. The endpoints get some kind of transaction ids which I want to add to the log messages written by Pythons logging package. In Javas log4j world this is called nested diagnostic context (NDC), which can be set in the beginning on a transaction, and in turn is added to each logger call later on during the transaction.
Logging is configured like this:
import logging
import os
import pathlib

from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from typing import Optional


class LoggerConfig:
    log_format = '%(asctime)s | %(filename)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s'

    def __init__(
            self,
            log_file_path: Optional[pathlib.Path],
            log_to_console: bool,
            max_log_bytes: int,
            n_backup_files: int,
            level: int
    ):
        self.log_file_path = log_file_path
        self.log_to_console = log_to_console
        self.max_log_size = max_log_bytes
        self.backup_count = n_backup_files
        self.level = level

        self._setup()

    def _setup(self):
        handlers = []

        if self.log_file_path is not None:
            if self.log_file_path.is_file():
                os.remove(self.log_file_path)  # clear if exists

            file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(
                self.log_file_path,
                maxBytes=self.max_log_size,
                backupCount=self.backup_count
            )
            file_handler.setLevel(self.level)
            fmt = logging.Formatter(LoggerConfig.log_format)
            file_handler.setFormatter(fmt=fmt)
            handlers.append(file_handler)

        if self.log_to_console:
            console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            console_handler.setLevel(level=self.level)
            fmt = logging.Formatter(LoggerConfig.log_format)
            console_handler.setFormatter(fmt=fmt)
            handlers.append(console_handler)

        logging.basicConfig(level=self.level, handlers=handlers)


from __future__ import annotations

from fastapi import FastAPI

import log.basis_config as basis_log_config
from log.LoggerConfig import LoggerConfig

from package_a import router as a_router
from package_b import router as b_router
from package_c import router as c_router
from package_d import router as d_router


LoggerConfig(
    log_file_path=basis_log_config.log_file_path,
    log_to_console=basis_log_config.log_to_console,
    max_log_bytes=basis_log_config.max_log_bytes,
    n_backup_files=basis_log_config.n_backup_files,
    level=basis_log_config.level
)

app = FastAPI(
    title='FastAPI',
    version='0.1.0',
    servers=[{'url': 'https://test:123/v1'}],
)

app.include_router(a_router)
app.include_router(b_router)
app.include_router(c_router)
app.include_router(d_router)


Then in the routers, the endpoints are defined, like this:
router = APIRouter()

@router.delete(
    "/app/res1/{id}",
    responses={
        404: {"description": "Id not found"},
    },
    tags=["app"],
    response_model_by_alias=True,
)
async def res1(
    id: int = Path(..., description="Transaction Id"),
) -> None:
    return await app_api.res1(id)

File app_api.py:
@async_http_exception
async def res1(id: int) -> object:
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.info(...)


What I tried so far is to add a logger adapter which can add the transaction id.
class TransactionLoggerAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return f"[transaction_id={self.extra['transaction_id']:>5}] {msg}", kwargs

Adapted file app_api.py:
@async_http_exception
async def res1(id: int) -> object:
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger = TransactionLoggerAdapter(logger, {'transaction_id': id})
    logger.info(...)


The problem I face is, that within the function res1 the transaction_id is appended to the log messages, but I can not get it in when code from other classes and modules/packages is executed from within res1.
I can for sure pass the logger into the deep space of code, but not all used packages are developed by me, so I can not hand in the logger which is wrapped by that LoggerAdapter.
How can I solve this issue?
